# Adding own CSS to TYPO3 backend [v9]

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I am trying to add some CSS styles to the TYPO3 backend (v9). I've added the stylesheet and the following line to the `ext_tables.php` of my own extension (as described in the file `typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Template/DocumentTemplate.php`).

```
$GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins'][$_EXTKEY]['stylesheetDirectories'] = ['EXT:my_extension/styles.css'];
```

When I check the configuration, the new entry show up, so that looks fine. But I don't see any style changes to the backend.

Any ideas anyone? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the key value (`stylesheetDirectories`) indicates, this should point to a directory. It will add all `.css` files in that directory.

Also, don't set `$GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins'][$_EXTKEY]['stylesheetDirectories']` as a new array, but use `$GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins'][$_EXTKEY]['stylesheetDirectories'][] = 'EXT:my_extension/styles/';`. That way other extensions can also add stylesheets without it being overwritten by your extension.

Comment: Please don't use $_EXTKEY in ext_tables.php anymore (since TYPO3 >= v10), see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/BestPractises/ConfigurationFiles.html#configuration-files-ext-tables-php-ext-localconf-php

Comment: I don't quite see the "That way other extensions can also add stylesheets without it being overwritten by your extension.". The snippet already uses the extension key in the array (though apart from that it is always a good recommendation)